# Minimal SOP in Boolean

Tags: logic, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I have a problem with the following.

```
F = A'BC' + A
  = A + A'BC'
  = A + BC'
```

It might be straight forward but I would like if someone could shed some light on the equation and how it becomes so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
F = A'BC' + A
  = A + A'BC'---> Associative rule(A+B = B+A)
  = A + BC'  ---> Reduction rule (A+A'X = A+X)
```

A+A'X = A+X using truth table, both the results for A+A'X and A+X matches for all values of A and and hence they can be replaced with one another.

```
 | A  |  X | A+A'X   |  A+X  |
 | 0  |  0 | 0+1.0=0 | 0+0=0 |
 | 0  |  1 | 0+1.1=1 | 0+1=1 |
 | 1  |  0 | 1+0.0=1 | 1+0=1 |
 | 1  |  1 | 1+0.1=1 | 1+1=1 |
```

Another explanation can be found at http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-7/boolean-rules-for-simplification/.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually pretty simple. If you convert the function to a logic table, you get the following:

```
 A | B | C |
 1 | - | - |
 0 | 1 | 0 |
```

The `-` are so-called "don’t cares", where the value does not matter. As we have don’t cares for `B` and `C` when `A=1`, we can also write the table like this:

```
 A | B | C |
 1 | - | - |
 1 | 1 | 0 |
 0 | 1 | 0 |
```

(This is actually redundant, as the first line also covers the second line).

That table can be shortened to

```
 A | B | C |
 1 | - | - |
 - | 1 | 0 |
```

So now we have the function

```
A + BC'
```

directly derived from the table.